# Flutter Set specific days of the week notifications

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to be notified on certain days of the week at a specific time using the local notices package.

Certain days of the week can be notified. But I don't know how to be notified on certain days of the week.

The Day.Monday part contains only the value, but no array.
I'd like to add more than two days of the week to this part.

Please help me with how to solve this problem.
Thank you.

Package Example Source ( https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications/example ) :

```
Future<void> _showWeeklyAtDayAndTime() async {
  var time = Time(20, 24, 0);
  var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'show weekly channel id',
      'show weekly channel name',
      'show weekly description');
  var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();
  var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
      androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.showWeeklyAtDayAndTime(
      0,
      'show weekly title',
      'Weekly notification shown on Monday at approximately ${_toTwoDigitString(time.hour)}:${_toTwoDigitString(time.minute)}:${_toTwoDigitString(time.second)}',
      Day.Monday,
      time,
      platformChannelSpecifics);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to schedule weekly notifications for some specific days in this package. The only thing you can do is to schedule same notification for each day separately.

Comment: Thank you for the good guidelines.
I need to think about it.